# Exclude rows where ID is duplicated but 3rd column has "unknown

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have this dataset where there are rows with duplicate personIDs but different pcpgrouper2. I only want to exclude "Unknown" where there are more than 1 of the same PersonID and one of them is "Unknown". If the ID has only one row with "Unknown" then keep that row.

| Name | PersonID | PCPGrouper |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABBAN, AVRIL | 1094893 | Unknown |
| ABBIS,CHLOE | 1114294 | T Docs |
| ABBIS,CHLOE | 1114294 | Unknown |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using the following SQL query (assuming you are using SQL):

```sql
SELECT Name, PersonID, PCPGrouper
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE PCPGrouper != 'Unknown' OR
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID AND
                t2.PCPGrouper != 'Unknown'
      );
```

The above logic retains any person record whose grouper value is not unknown or is unknown but there is no other value.